# Date in m/d/y in timestamp. How to convert to dd-mm-yyyy in mysql

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, timestamp

I have a DATETIME column like below one:

```
| XDATE           |
| 9/21/03 00:00:00|
| 8/12/10 00:00:00|
| 7/30/01 00:00:00| 
| 7/1/03 00:00:00 |
| 6/16/20 00:00:00|
| 5/31/04 00:00:00|
| 11/7/05 00:00:00|
| 1/8/06 00:00:00 |
```

[image: XDate column]

I want to convert XDATE column to “DD-MMYYYY” format.

I tried below

```
date_format(Xdate, '%d-%m-%Y').
```

But the result has null because it considers the format yyyy-mm-dd and converts to dd-mm-yyyy.

```
| XDATE           |
| 9/21/03 00:00:00| null
| 8/12/10 00:00:00|
| 7/30/01 00:00:00| null
| 7/1/03 00:00:00 | 
| 6/16/20 00:00:00| null
| 5/31/04 00:00:00|
| 11/7/05 00:00:00|
| 1/8/06 00:00:00 |
```

[image: Result]

How to solve this problem and convert Xdate column to show only the date, and format it by “DD-MMYYYY"

Comment: DATE_FORMAT converts date to string whereas you need in backward transformation. Use STR_TO_DATE().

Comment: converting cost very mucg time, you should store dates always in mysql dateformat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :

```
create table test_tbl(
xdate varchar(50) );


INSERT INTO test_tbl
VALUES ('9/21/03 00:00:00'),
       ('8/12/10 00:00:00'),
        ('7/1/03 00:00:00') ;

SELECT   date_format(str_to_date(xdate, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y') as xdate
from test_tbl;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/126

> For more info on date-format:
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format
>
> For more info on str-to-date:
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: `SELECT STR_TO_DATE(xdate, '%m/%d/%Y') AS xdate from test_tbl;` is enough.

Comment: @Akina you can't produce `DD-MM-YYYY` with only STR_TO_DATE, DATE_FORMAT was only to produce the OP expected date format

Comment: *you can't produce DD-MM-YYYY with only STR_TO_DATE* Sorry, I was inattentive.